# Updating a static map from database when other thread can access it

Tags: java, concurrency, static

```
class A {
static Map<String,ColA> mapA;
static const int a = 12;
static Map<String,colB> mapB;
}
```

Q1>
Now I need to update the Map from database every 10 minutes. There can be multiple threads which can be accessing mapA. So if I update in one of the threads using synchronized how will there be any instance where the thread may break when the updating is going on. If so how to solve this problem??

Q2>
Also I have different member of the class. Some of them are constants and some of them are loaded from memory. However all of them have one common property. They are always the same for all the instances (static). So does it make sense to have everything in one class or should we have two separate classes?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what kind of implementation you're using for your maps, but I recommend you use [ConcurrentHashMap](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html). Also, if you're using that class for a Web Application, don't use static variables instead use a caching system like [ehCache](http://ehcache.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I need to update the Map from database in every 10 minutes. There can be multiple thread which can be accessing mapA. So if i update in one of the thread using synchonized how will there be any instance where the thread may break when the updation is going on. If so how to solve this problem??

This sounds like somewhere it might be worth using `AtomicReference`. Fetch the data from the database, put it in a map, and then atomically swap it with the "old" map. That way any client code can fetch the map and know that it's effectively a snapshot which won't change under them.

> Also I have different member of the class. Some of them are constants and some of them are loaded from memrory. However all of them have one common property. They are always same for all the instances(static). So does it make sense to have everything in one class or should we have two seperate class.

That's a pretty vague description. None of the attributes you've specified (some being constants, some being loaded from memory, all having one common property, all being static) have anything to do with whether they should be in the same class or not.

Comment: Hi the classA is a type of Manager class and provides the rest of the Application to access those variables defined in A. All this value does not depend on the type of input and is constant at a given point. Many place in the code will be needing those variable and will  call classA to get those variables. So for the variables which will not change the code will have a simple getter and for which it will change it will checkForUpdate and then return the value

Comment: @user1479802: None of that really gives any indication of whether the various variables belong together though. I would actually strongly discourage you from these global variables in the first place - global state makes testing very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

`1. If synchronization is used on the group of statement or the method which is responsible` for changing the crucial state of the MapA, then i dont think there will be a problem.`

`2. I am not getting a clear understanding of your 2nd question, but still you can divide` `them in to classes using cohesive principle.`

**Cohesive class means, A class having methods which reflects its name .**

eg:

```
 `class Animal with methods like Sound, Movements, etc...`
```